# Select ObjectSet by entity type

Tags: entity-framework

I need a way to select objects given the `name:string` of the object and `ObjectContext`, but dont know how to do this.

I will use this to create a generic lookup dropdown editor template in `ASP.MVC`

So when view contains `@Html.EditorFor` (`student=>student.School`), it will show dropDown containing list of schools.

I get the target entity name from `relation.ToMember`, but don't know how to query data records with this input.

Currently I have added a custom method which gets string and returns innumerable and inside that I have a big switch case "School": return `this.SchooleSet`;

Is there a right way to do this.

I also want to add a generic method which allows me to query using syntax like `ctx.Select<Teacher>().Where(...)`

again here I have implemented with switch but there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [CreateObjectSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383062.aspx) method.

```
var q = ctx.CreateObjectSet<Teacher>().Where(...);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess this answers second part of my question where I have type parameter.
I wonder if I need to keep reference to the created ObjectSet or I can create it each time which means it always uses same IdentityMap

Comment: The first part of the question is still open. Can I get it by string or should I use reflection to call above mentioned method CreateObjectSet?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. Can you clarify?